# Implementation of Pause and Resume in PHP-Rest API

Tags: php, web-services, rest, amazon-web-services

I am trying to upload the file to amazon s3 bucket using the PHP-REST API and my code is working fine..but I want to know how can I implement the pause and resume functionality by using the Rest API.
currently I am following one blog post for uploading the file:-
**http://www.anyexample.com/programming/php/uploading_files_to_amazon_s3_with_rest_api.xml**

So, I need to implement the reusme and pause fucntionality..Plz help me on this..

Comment: Pause upload? There isn't a way to do that in PHP. PHP just uses commands to upload a file and they are just executed, you cannot alter them.

Comment: Is any other way to do the pause and resume functionality ?? but that should work with the help of PHP langauage..Because I have a php web application , from there I need to give the upload data , pause and resume option...

Comment: Like I said. I never heard about pause upload in PHP. PHP is a server side scripting. As soon as you start a process you cannot pause it from client side: eg. Browser

Comment: Hi Lorga, Thanks for reply.. Do u  know how the amazon is using the pause and resume functionality inside the console..(Means when we login into Amazon console panel, they have direct upload option for any data.)????

Comment: Iorga ... with i :). Don't know ... but I'm sure it's not PHP :)

Comment: So ,it means ..we cannot achieve this functionality in PHP...but according to amazon documents they are saying like we can do this in RESt Api...so we should use the rest api with any other language except PHP..am I correct??

Comment: REST API doesn't mean they use same language, it's just an API, you can connect with almost any language as long as you send same format and data. like they are saying in first lines in the link you posted: `Here is an example of command line non-interactive php script which uploads file to Amazon S3 (Simple Storage Service).` NON-INTERACTIVE - that explains very well :)

Comment: Yes, you are correct...thatswhy I am asking...can I use the Rest api with PHP language to achieve the pause and resume functionality.???

Comment: Sorry, I didnt get any example link...

Comment: Have you ever worked to implement the resume and pause function in any language??